# projections of 3d vector on respective planes

Tags: math, vector, 3d, geometry, plane

I have a 3d vector defined by start and end coordinates (x0,y0,z0 and x1,y1,z1). Also I know the angles made by this vector to the x,y,z axes. Does some one know how do I get to know the angles induced by the vector in xy, yz and zx planes?

Comment: Angles *in* the plane or *to* the plane? If the former, then you want the angle to *which* axis?

Comment: angles projected to the 2d plane

Answer (score 0):

Projection of given segment to OXY plane is segment with coordinates `(x1, y1) - (x2, y2)`.

It forms angle relative to OX-axis:

```
 Axy = atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)
```

Angle between segment and its projection on OXY plane is

```
Pxy = arcsin((z2 - z1) / Sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2)
```